# Is there a way to concat class names and other characters into a string with ## and # macros

Tags: c++, c++11, qt5

I'm developing qt application and we know that qt's `SLOT` and `SIGNAL` can convert input as `char *` which is needed by `connect` function. But my signals are coded as macros:

```cpp
//NOTE following line is NOT RIGHT way, but just my idea
#define TEST_SIGNAL(name) #name##Changed##(##)
```

If I call this macro somewhere as:

```cpp
// given defined integer variable
// int testInt;
TEST_SIGNAL(testInt)
```

which should generate following string:

> "testIntChanged()"

So I can call that macro definition within `connect`:

```cpp
// here we can focus on only second parameter of connect, eg. TEST_SIGNAL(testInt)
// given other parameters
connect(this, TEST_SIGNAL(testInt), this, SLOT(testIntHandle()));
```

Is it possible with macros `#` and `##` in C++? If not, which is the better way?

Comment: Stop using qt4 style slots and signals macros.

Comment: @Botje Thanks for reply. For now, In some cases, I need this feature within existing project.

Comment: `#define TEST_SIGNAL(name) #name "Changed()"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really cannot escape the Qt4 style signals/slots:

```
#define TEST_SIGNAL(name) SIGNAL(name##Changed())
```

This makes `TEST_SIGNAL(testInt)` identical to `SIGNAL(testIntChanged())`.